# ternary foreach nested within if / else

Tags: php, ternary

I was wondering how I can rewrite the following using ternary within ternary or within alternative syntax.

```
$tags = get_the_tags();
if (!empty($tags)) {
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        echo $tag->name . ', ';
    }    
} else {
    echo 'foobar';
}
```

Comment: Can you share what you've tried?

Comment: No better place to start, than the manual http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php - *Right Sam?* - @JayBlanchard

Comment: Can you please print $tags and provide an array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No such thing as ternary foreach. You can however make your conditional statement ternary like this

```
echo empty($tags) ? 'foobar' :
implode(', ',array_map(create_function('$o', 'return $o->name;'),$tags)) ;
```

;)

**Output**

> foo, bar, John

**Explanation**

We create a closure that returns an array of the `name` property of all your tags then simply implode it like you want. If tags are empty we show `foobar`, all in one line.

Comment: woah, you beat me to it

Comment: Thanks, I knew I was missing something

Answer (score 2):

Solution with `array_reduce`:

```
echo (empty($tags))? 'foobar': array_reduce($tags, function($prev, $item){
    return $prev.(($prev)? ", " : "").$item->name;
}, "");

// the output:
bob, john, max
```

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-reduce.php